# Rails, Google OAuth and 2 different login scopes (Admin/Front)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth

I am using the gem [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)

In my case I have 2 different scopes:

- AdminUsers
- FrontUsers

I would like to use Google Auth for both but as there is only one Callback URL I don't know how can identify if this authentication is coming from a FrontUser or and AdminUser.

I can not use the "name" or "email" as an identifier of the scope because the same Name/Email can be in both scopes.

I have tried to define 2 different Callback URLs and adding the param `redirect_uri` to the first auth URL:

For the Admin login:

```
<%= link_to "Login with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2?redirect_uri=http://example.com/admin/auth/google_oauth2/callback" %>
```

For the Front login:

```
<%= link_to "Login with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2?redirect_uri=http://example.com/front/auth/google_oauth2/callback" %>
```

It works almost perfect, the problem is that the `request.env['omniauth.auth']` is empty as we have seen in other [issues](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/326).

I have tried this too:

```
<%= link_to "Login with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2?callback_path=/admin/auth/google_oauth2/callback" %>
```

But the param `callback_path` is just ignored.

If I just could at least send a flag parameter that would be returned in the callback would be enough.

What solution can I implement?

Answer (score 0):

I see, in fact, I can send a param that is returned in the callback:

```
<%= link_to "Login with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2?from=admin" %>
```

And then in the callback controller action I can see it:

```
request.env['omniauth.params']['from']
```

Then I can fork my logic based on that.